# remove duplicates from list of variables VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of variables, (longs)

These have the name Or1 to Or100. 
All these are set by picking a random cell from range in a Excel Spreadsheet.

I also have a boolean for each OR set as Or1x to or100x. This boolean shall be true if there is duplicate values. If Or1 is the same as or67 both or1x and or67x is true. As of now the only way I've figured out how to do this is by an array of if statements. The problem is that this is so long, and slow. Is there any other smart solution here?

Comment: Show us your "slow" code, please.

Comment: If or1 = or2 then
or1x = true
or2x= true
else end if.

and so on and so on.

Comment: so where do you use array?

Comment: Post your full code properly formatted in your question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

the most simple and general (not the fastest) way is using dictionary to count elements

```
set dict=createobject("Scripting.Dictionary")
for i=1 to 100
  dict(Or(i))=dict(Or(i))+1
next
for i=1 to 100
  Orx(i)=(dict(Or(i))>1)
next
```

(I've assumed, that Or and Orx are arrays.)